# Erro ao testar ActivatedRoute com jest angular 9

Tags: jasmine, jest, angular, testes-unitarios

Primeiro agradeço por ler a minha questão!

Cenário:

Estou realizando o teste de uma aplicação angular 9 com jest
de um componente que utiliza uma classe 'resolve'.

Tentei configurar um mock para o resolve, mas ao rodar os testes sempre recebo um erro,
dizendo que a propriedade 'data' do snapshot não está definida.

Segue o print da configuração de teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: essa sua mock tem essa propriedade snapshot e data?

Comment: Olá Eduardo.

tentei dessa forma tbm:

route: {
  snapshot: {
    data: {campanhas: campanhasFake}
  }
}

Mas da forma que está montada o jest deveria simular essas propriedades snapshot e data.

Answer (score 0):

errado: *route*: { snapshot: { data: {campanhas: campanhasFake} } }

correto: { snapshot: { data: {campanhas: campanhasFake} } }

o erro era utilizar a propriedade route no objeto.